# Visual Studio 2015 CTP installer doesn't start

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've tried to run the installer of Visual Studio 2015 CTP but when I tried to execute it, it only shows the Visual Studio logo but it doesn't execute anything anything else after that. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you have to execute it using the option menu 'Run as Administrator', otherwise, it will not start at all. That's weird because old versions prompt you to authorize the execution as Administrator.